# ParseException when using allowCustomObjectId on Parse-SDK-Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, parse-platform, parse-server

I am currently testing something with the parse server in Flutter. I would like to set the object ids in the database itself. In the Parse SDK Flutter there is also in the create() function an attribute called: allowCustomObjectId, which can be set to True. However, I have not yet been able to find any information on how I can finally set this Custom ObjectId with:

```
ParseObject().set(_id, "MyId")
```

or

```
ParseObject().objectId = "MyId"
```

I get an error in any case:

```
I/flutter ( 4854): ParseException (Type: InvalidKeyName) :
I/flutter ( 4854): Code: 105
I/flutter ( 4854): Message: objectId is an invalid field name.----
```

Maybe someone can help me here?

Comment: Have you enabled custom object ids in your Parse Server?

Comment: Oh thanks, this solved it.